# How to display all the tables with more information (create date, size,...) in a MySQL database?

Tags: sql, mysql

Searched and searched and gave up. All I want is more info on a MySQL table or better yet, a list of all tables in a MySQL database in the descending/ascending order of their create date.

Something like this :

```
SHOW TABLES FROM MyDB ORDER BY CREATE_DATE;
```

Donnie's answer did the trick :

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DBName' order by create_time desc;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` is the most easily queryable, but that doesn't have creation date.
[show table status](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html) does return creation date information.  You can probably craft something to get the table name out of `information_schema`, then call `show table status` on each.

Comment: Well, it sure does have create_time or is it a different version? I updated the answer in the question! Thanks much!

Comment: @ThinkCode - huh, I didn't think it did.  Well, yay! :)